# How to get custom space between Jlist item?

Tags: java, swing

I have added few images to my JList showing them horizontally.

Now I want to increase the space between the images in the JList.

Could anyone suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Set a fixed width and height for your JList items.

```
list.setFixedCellHeight(50);
list.setFixedCellWidth(100);
```

The `setBorder()` method is for setting border insets. You can also add it to the lines above to make margin spaces arranged:

```
list.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10, 10, 10));
```

Comment: `setBorder` won't change the border of list items

Comment: @stryba i was aware of it, but it can help the first 2 lines. edited my answer.

Comment: @deporter Yes it is helpful i got what i wanted thanks....
i just used this and its done 
list.setFixedCellHeight(50);
list.setFixedCellWidth(100);

Comment: If I use __setFixedCellHeight(x)__, will it be the same on every platform, display size? Which unit is the argument?

Comment: @trinity420 All integer sizes in Swing are in pixels.  There are a couple places where the code is working with picos and whatnot, but they're few and far between and documented as such.

Comment: @trinity420 If you need to do platform- or display-specific measuring, you're probably looking at things like `java.awt.font.FontRenderContext` or `java.awt.Graphics2D`, which get into display transformations.

Answer (score 7):

Provide your own `ListCellRenderer` which can introduce, e.g., an empty border with a specific width.

Comment: @AshishDonvir could you try my method? was it useful?

Answer (score 5):

there are two ways

1) `Renderer` can returns `JLabel`, set [EmptyBorders()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)

2) a little bit complicated way is put there [JSeparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/separator.html)